# Matplotlib scatter plot with density histograms on the sides

Tags: matplotlib

I don't know any way to describe this plot, but I need to do it preferably with matplotlib. If there is a name for this plot, I would love to know it.

It can be found on page 10 of this PLOS ONE paper (Figure 6): http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0093590

Basically, each section is made up of three plots. One scatter plot, and two histograms that show the density of points in each region, one for each axis.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `seaborn`'s  `jointplot` is what you are looking for. See e.g. http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/plotting_distributions.html

Comment: That's amazing. Bookmarking for future use. Thanks.